# Neural ODE and Adjoint method

Tags: neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, gradient-descent, differential-equations

I am trying to understand the paper [NeuralODE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366) which is very interesting.
I get the general idea and the proof they give about the dynamics of the adjoint are fairly simple.

They define a network $f$, parametrized by $\theta$:
$$
\frac{dz(t)}{dt} = f(z(t), t, \theta)
$$

Of course, to train the network, it is important to compute the gradient of the loss with respect to the parameters: $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} $$
However, I do not understand why it is needed to compute the gradient of the loss with respect to $z(t)$ and to $t$ also:
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial z(t)}, \frac{\partial L}{\partial t} $$

I would say once you have the first gradient, it is possible to update the weights of the neural network and train it right?

Is this needed only because **torch.autograd.Function** (that they are using in original implementation) needs it to build the computation graph correctly? Or is there any other reason behind it?

Thank you for you help!